# Proving rigorously that if $3\mid(a+b)$ then $3\mid(a^3+b^3)$ using divisibility definition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, definition, divisibility

Let $a,b\in \mathbb Z$. Prove rigorously using divisibility definition that if $3\mid(a+b)$ then $3\mid(a^3+b^3)$

After a bit of algebra I get that

$$3\overset{?}{\mid}(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)$$

So now how do I justify that it's divisible by $3$? Can I show that both expressions are divisible by $3$ separately? Then what do I mention to justify the sum of divisors is divisible?

Comment: Isolate $a+b$ in the expression you already have.

Comment: Or observe that $3m-3n=3(m-n)$, so that if each term is a multiple of $3$, so is their difference.

Comment: We have $a+b=3k$ for some $k$, so by your identity $a^3+b^3=3\left(9k^3-ab(a+b)\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3\mid a+b\mid (a+b)((a+b)^2-3ab)=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)=a^3+b^3$$

or

$$3\mid a+b\mid (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=a^3+b^3$$

---

This uses the fact that $a\mid b\mid c\implies a \mid c$, where $a\neq 0$. It can be proved [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) as follows:
$\begin{cases}a\mid b\implies b=am,m\in\mathbb Z\\b\mid c\implies c=bk,k\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}c=bk=a(mk)\\mk\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}\implies a\mid c.\ \ \ \square$

Answer (score 4):

If $3|(a+b)$ then $3|((a+b)^3-3a^2b-3ab^2)$ so $3|a^3+b^3$.